# Inserting pictures (graphics) into the Header on the Mac version

Tags: excel, macos, vba, office-2016

On the previous version of Excel for Mac, the following block of code was working:

```
With Worksheets(sheetName)
    .Activate
    .PageSetup.Zoom = False
    .PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape
    '* 2.10.08 START
    If Left(sheetName, 5) = "Order" Then
        .PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = 1
    Else
        .PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = False
    End If
    '* 2.10.08 END
    .PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1
    .PageSetup.LeftFooter = "&L&D - &T"
    .PageSetup.CenterFooter = ""
    .PageSetup.RightFooter = "&RPage &P / &N"
    .PageSetup.RightHeaderPicture.Filename = ActiveWorkbook.Path + ":" + "Logo 28 02 2014.jpg"
    .PageSetup.RightHeader = "&G"
    '.PageSetup.Right
    .UsedRange.Select
End With
```

On Excel 2016 (Mac) the `.PageSetup.RightHeaderPicture.Filename =` line tosses a 1004 error.

Using Macro Recorder, I discovered that the Header/Footer tool does not appear to support inserting pictures (graphics) into the Header on the Mac version (it does on Windows).

Is there a workaround, or did Microsoft take away a piece of functionality on the Mac version in Office 2016?